# ls it possible to have 2 words to compare with IF?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off

:menu
echo.
echo Hello! Would you like to play this Quiz game?
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto Q1

:Q1
echo.
echo Who is the CEO of Google?
set /p Q1A=
if %Q1A% equ Sundar Pichai goto Welldone;

:Welldone
echo cool
pause
```

Simple code.

As soon as I answer `Q1`with the correct answer "Sundar Pichai", the bat file closes.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Please help me!

Edit: If I type "SundarPichai" without spaces, it works.
But how do I make it work with spaces?

Comment: `if "%q1a%" == "Sundar Pichai"` or  `if /i "%q1a%" == "Sundar Pichai"` to be case insensitive. Also you're code will always fall into `:Welldone`. Place and `exit/B` before the label.

Comment: The above is just a part of the code.
I'll try to fix it when I get back to my PC.

Comment: This problem have no relation with `set /p` command, but with `if` command. I suggest you to edit the question title...

Comment: Thank you.
Can you please refer me to a website which included these "tags?".
Thank you.

Comment: @elzooilogico the problem is not solved even after adding the double quotes. `if /i %Q1A% == "Sundar Pichai" goto Welldone`

Comment: @KusaShaha: read again. You have to put *both sides*  into quotes.

Comment: @Stephan
Thanks a lot!